# Subcategorias dentro de sua respectiva Categoria no menu

Tags: php, html

Olá, criei um menu que busca as informações no banco de dados.
Tenho uma tabela com as categorias e outra com as subcategorias, ate ai beleza, a minha dificuldade é fazer que cada subcategoria fique listada dentro de sua respectiva categoria (exemplo abaixo)...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não estou conseguindo, ele fica conforme exemplo abaixo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo estou anexando o código usado para o menu...

```
    <?php
    include "../conexao.php";
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria order by nome")or die(mysql_error());
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> <?php echo $res['nome'];?> </a>
            <?php
              }
            ?>
    <?php
    include "../conexao.php";
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_categoria order by nome")or die(mysql_error());
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="prod_index_subcategoria.php?codsubcategoria=<?php echo $res['nome'];?>"><?php echo $res['nome'];?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php
              }
            ?>
            </ul>
```

Abaixo estruturas das tabelas usadas...
Categorias:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Subcategorias:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Produtos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se os amigos puderem me ajudar dizendo onde estou errando, ou mesmo o que fazer para que consiga chegar ao meu objetivo, que são as Subcategorias sendo listadas dentro de suas respectivas Categorias.

No aguardo da ajuda dos amigos, e desde já agradecendo a atenção de todos ao meu problema.

Estou editando o Post com a nova linha de código abaixo com Inner Join...

```
        <?php

    include "../conexao.php";
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria INNER JOIN sub_categoria ON categoria.nome_cat = sub_categoria.nome_cat")or die(mysql_error());
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> <?php echo $res['nome_cat'];?> </a>
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="prod_index_subcategoria.php?codsubcategoria=<?php echo $res['nome'];?>"><?php echo $res['nome'];?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php
              }
            ?>
            </ul>
```

E estou anexando também as imagens das estruturas de Categorias e Sub-Categorias que me equivoquei anteriormente e publiquei a categoria em duplicidade.

Categoria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sub-Categoria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia postar a estrutura das tabelas categoria e subcategorias?

Comment: OK, Hebert de Lima, acabei de editar o Post com as estruturas usadas. Espero que ajude. Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

ok... enfim: primeiro crie essa função

```
//ler tabela
function DBRead($table, $param = null, $fields = "*"){
    $param  = ($param) ? " where {$param}": null;
    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$param}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);
    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else{
        while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] =$rs;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

//Executar query
function DBExecute($query, $id = false){
    $link   = DBConnect();
    $result = @mysqli_query($link,$query) or die (mysqli_error($link));

    if($id){
        $result = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        return $result;
    }

    DBClose($link);
    return $result;
}
//abre conexão
function DBConnect(){
    $link = @mysqli_connect('HOST','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DATABASE') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8') or die(mysqli_error($link));
    return $link;
}
//fecha conexão
function DBClose($link){
    @mysqli_close($link) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

na sua página coloque assim:

```
$cat = DBRead('cat');
foreach ($cat as $valueCat) {
    echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$valueCat['titulo'];
            echo '<ul>';
                $subcat = DBRead('subcat','fk_id ="'.$valueCat['id'].'"');
                foreach ($subcat as $valueSub) {
                    if($valueCat['id'] = $valueSub['fk_id']){
                        echo '<li>'.$valueSub['sub titulo'] .'<br/> </li>';
                    }
                }
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
```

Obs: não esqueça das `includes`!
Obs: **cat** = Categoria, **subcat** = subcategoria
A chave Primária da tabela **Categoria** precisa ser Estrangeira na tabela **Subcategoria** relação (1,N) 

Ex:

```
Tab Cat          |  Tab Subcat
id 1             |  fk_id 1
                 |  fk_id 1
                 |  fk_id 1
id 2             |  fk_id 2
                 |  fk_id 2
```

etc... Boa sorte.

Comment: Olá Hebert, eu tentei seguir a sua sugestão em criar um Inner Join, quase funcionou, mas as categorias estão se duplicando, e não sei como fazer para que as Sub-Categorias fiquem dentro de cada Categorias referente a elas. Estou postando o endereço http://www.efacilfacil.com.br/prod_index.php, para que vc. possa verificar o que esta acontecendo com o menu das Categorias, e postarei também as estruturas corretamente da Categoria e Sub, valeu? Grande abraço e agradeço pela sua atenção e ajuda ao meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

já pensou na possibilidade de adicionar um campo id_cat (exemplo), em que ficasse o id da categoria pai, dentro da tabela subcategorias? Desta forma, poderia fazer o select chamando apenas as subcategorias de acordo com o id da categoria pai.

Answer (score 0):

Cara na sub categoria você precisa ter o código da categoria.
E no `SELECT` da sub categoria você coloca `codigo_categoria = $res_categoria['id']` assim você pode criar uma relação entre as tabelas.
obs: Você não precisa chamar a conexão mais de uma vez no mesmo arquivo